# Python - Retrieving certain indicies from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of numbers with shape (1220,) called `x`

I'm looking at numbers greater than 1.0,

```
mask1 =  [i for i in x if i>1.0 ]
```

returning

```
[1.2958354, 1.0839227, 1.1919032]
```

My question now is then how am able to determine the index location of these values in my initial array `x`?

I've tried each individually, but an error occurs

```
list(x).index(1.2958354)

ValueError: 1.2958354 is not in list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enumerate function, for example:

```
mask1 =  [(i, value) for i, value in enumerate(x) if value>1.0 ]
print mask1
```

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged this as `numpy`, and describe a `shape` (not `len`).  Which leads me to think you have a numpy array.

```
In [665]: x=np.random.rand(10)
In [666]: x
Out[666]: 
array([ 0.6708692 ,  0.2856505 ,  0.19186508,  0.59411697,  0.1188686 ,
        0.54921919,  0.77402055,  0.12569494,  0.08807101,  0.11623299])
In [667]: x>.5
Out[667]: array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [668]: list(x).index(.6708692)
ValueError: 0.6708692 is not in list
```

The reason for the `ValueError` is that you are looking for a float, and those often don't exactly match.  If the array was of ints, then such an index would work.

```
In [669]: list(np.arange(10)).index(5)
Out[669]: 5
```

This reasoning applies whether `x` was an array or a list.

`numpy` has a `where` that returns the index of boolean true values in an array

```
In [670]: np.where(x>.5)
Out[670]: (array([0, 3, 5, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

`x>.5` is the boolean array as shown above, and `[0,3,5,6]` the index values where this is true.

```
In [671]: x[np.where(x>.5)]
Out[671]: array([ 0.6708692 ,  0.59411697,  0.54921919,  0.77402055])
```

The equality test doesn't work any better

```
In [672]: x[np.where(x==0.6708692)]
Out[672]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

For floats there is the concept of `close` - the difference is within some tolerance (`np.allclose` is particularly useful):

```
In [679]: np.where(np.isclose(x,0.59411697))
Out[679]: (array([3], dtype=int32),)
```

For lists, one of the enumerate solutions is great, and also works with 1d arrays.  But it is already an array, use the `where`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mask1 =  [i for i in range(len(x)) if x[i]>1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` function on `x`, which will return the first index of each value. To get a list of all the indices from `mask1` try:

```
map(x.index, mask1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mask_1 = [index for index, value in enumerate(x) if value > 1.0]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `enumerate()` to get the index and value together:

```
mask1 = [(i,v) for i,v in enumerate(x) if v > 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate to create tuple pairs of the index and the filtered value, then use zip with the * operator to unpack the variables into separate lists.

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])

idx, vals = zip(*[(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(a) if v > 1])

>>> idx
(2, 3)

>>> vals
(2, 3)
```